# How to create google sheet document using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to create google sheet document using node js.
I found libraries only for reading and writing, not for create new one.
Can anyone help me, or recommend some way how can I do it?

Comment: You have an entire documentation at your disposal. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#node.js

Comment: Looks like it is creating a new list in existing file

Answer (score 0):

You just need check it out here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet. I think you will find what you need.

Comment: There is no way how to create new file

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new Spreadsheet with Node.js you can either use [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) with the method [create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) (the one I would recommend), [this is an example of its implementation in Node.js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#node.js) or with [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) with the method [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).

[Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) is the quickstart guide for Sheets API for Node.js and [this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) is the quickstart guide for Drive API.